# Getting DocType of Requesting page - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, doctype

i am trying to get some html code from an aspx page (assume serverPage.aspx) and binding those content in my page (assume clientPage.aspx).

Here i need to get the docType of the clientPage. How can i get it in serverPage or i can pass it from clientPage, then how can i get it from clientPage's code behind.